# Bash remove part of a string

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, cut

If I have the following code:

```
twitter="https://twitter.com/username"
```

How do I use something like sed or awk to remove this:

```
https://twitter.com/
```

So I'm left with:

```
username
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task can be accomplished by `basename`:

```
$ basename https://twitter.com/username
username
```

Comment: That is a very interesting abuse of basename.

Comment: And, perhaps more interesting, `https://twitter.com/username` is a valid *path* in a Unix filesystem, besides being a URI...

Comment: (Though it would be okay for anything to remove one of the slashes separating the protocol, so nothing you can depend on.)

Comment: @kyrias, `basename` should work all the same with just one slash between the protocol scheme and the resource proper.

Comment: @RobertoReale Point was that while you can go from URL → UNIX path, you can't necessarily do a roundtrip.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `bash` variable expansion:

```
$ twitter="https://twitter.com/username"
$ echo "${twitter##*/}"
username
```

`##` removes the longest match from the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an external program, you can just use normal parameter substitution using the `#` to remove the prefix:

```
$ twitter="https://twitter.com/username"
$ echo ${twitter#https://twitter.com/}
username
```

Comment: @RobertoReale: The requirement of the problem was to remove the given prefix, what happens if the prefix is different or not present isn't specified so whether it's appropriate to remove the scheme, hostname and leading slash in all cases is not deducible from the problem statement.

Comment: That is what I call coding according to spec. Obviously code created this way won't be as maintainable as a more robust solution.

Comment: @user2672165: I admit that there is no error checking in my code but when the input doesn't match what the code is designed to do it might be just as wrong to remove the incorrect prefix without erroring as it would be to not remove the incorrect prefix without erroring. If the requirements were clarified then any option chosen might well require changing. I don't believe my solution is less maintainable than a more "robust" solution, whatever that might mean.

Answer (score 0):

Using BASH regex capability:

```
s="https://twitter.com/username"
[[ "$s" =~ /([^/]+)$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
username
```

For such a simple task regex might not be always needed but power of regex can be considered for more complex job like finding last but one string between slashes etc.